# Unable to fetch PACT from Pact Brocker in dotnet core while verifying provider side

Tags: .net, pact-broker

I have implemented PACT on consumer side in C# dotnet core and I was able to publish *.json pact file to PactBrocker using following code.

```
var pactPublisher = new PactPublisher("http://domain.pact.dius.com.au", new PactUriOptions("***", "***"));

pactPublisher.PublishToBroker($"..\pacts\userservice.api-event.api.json",
                        "1.0.2");
```

On provider side (again in C# dotnet core), when I try to verify the same published Pact, using a unit test case (see below code):

```
[Fact]
public void EnsureEventApiHonoursPactWithConsumer()
{        
    //Arrange
    // createing the "config" object

    //Act / Assert
    IPactVerifier pactVerifier = new PactVerifier(config);

          pactVerifier
            .ProviderState($"{_providerUri}/provider-states")
            .ServiceProvider("Event.API", _providerUri)
            .HonoursPactWith("UserService.API")
       .PactUri("http://domain.pact.dius.com.au/pacts/provider/Event.API/consumer/UserService.API/version/1.0.2", new PactUriOptions("***", "***")).Verify();
}
```

I get below **error** when I run that unit test.

> PactNet.PactFailureException : Pact verification failed. See output
>   for details.  If the output is empty please provide a custom
>   config.Outputters (IOutput) for your test framework, as we couldn't
>   write to the console.   at PactNet.Core.PactCoreHost`1.Start() in
>   C:\projects\pact-net\PactNet\Core\PactCoreHost.cs:line 139
>
> at Event.Test.EventApiTests.EnsureEventApiHonoursPactWithConsumer()
>   in C:\POC\pact2\Event.Api\Event.Test\EventAPITests.cs:line 55
>
> **Error reading file from**
>   http://domain.pact.dius.com.au/pacts/provider/Event.API/consumer/UserService.API/version/1.0.2
>
> **No connection could be made because the target machine actively**
>   **refused it. - connect(2) for "domain.pact.dius.com.au" port 80**
>   C:/POC/pact2/Event.Api/Event.Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/pact-win32/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in
>   `initialize'
>
> C:/POC/pact2/Event.Api/Event.Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/pact-win32/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in
>   `open'
>
> C:/POC/pact2/Event.Api/Event.Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/pact-win32/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in
>   `block in connect'
>
> C:/POC/pact2/Event.Api/Event.Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/pact-win32/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in
>   `timeout'
>
> C:/POC/pact2/Event.Api/Event.Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/pact-win32/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in
>   `connect'
>
> C:/POC/pact2/Event.Api/Event.Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/pact-win32/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in
>   `do_start'
>
> C:/POC/pact2/Event.Api/Event.Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/pact-win32/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in
>   `start'

Can someone please help fixing this error? The PACT broker server is not in my control. I got it from http://pact.dius.com.au/ site.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer. I was in my office's proxy environment. It works great at my home. Also I need to hit https (port 443) and not http (port 80).